# Running backgound thread every X seconds (Android Studio)

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency

I have a code that plays 5 sounds with 1 second delay between the sounds and I want this part of code to be executed every 5 seconds (so it will run in a row so far as a boolean variable is true, and when it becomes false the tread run stopped - I have a button to both start and stop this executions). Everything works perfectly, but the issue is that I can't get rid of the 5 seconds delay in the first time I click the button, so when I first click, the sounds beggins only after 5 seconds. How can I make it start right away and only after the first time start taking the delays?

Here is the button onClick code:

```
public void clickHandlerStartTempo(final View view) {
    if (!tempoOn) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Tempo!", Toast
                .LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tempoOn = true;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (tempoOn) {
                    runCode(view);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    } else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop Tempo!", Toast
                .LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tempoOn = false;
    }

}
```

And here is the runCode method:

```
public void runCode(View view) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            playSound(0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if (tempoOn) {
                    playSound(1);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    Log.i(TAG, "runCode: Thread id = " + thread.getId());
    thread.start();
}
```

I'm new to android development and any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about `TimerTask`? it'll be help in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to playsound without thread after that you will execute your reaming 5 second logic stop thread after 4 count.

```
public void onStartPress(){
    playSound();
    someMethod();
}

public void someMethod(){
    Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            playSound();
            someMethod();
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use actual `Threads` unless you really want to do something off the Ui thread. Most of the time you do want to keep things on the Ui thread.

For simple repeating tasks, you can easily repurpose the [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) class. Often with an (almost) infinite run time or `Long.MAX_VALUE` (292 million years). The fist `onTick` happens immediately after starting.

```
private CountDownTimer mTimer;
private void start() {
    if (mTimer == null) {
        mTimer = new CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 5000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // start a beeping countdown
                new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
                    private int state = 1;
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        playSound(state);
                        state = state + 1 % 2;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        playSound(0);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() { /* ignore, never happens */ }
        };
        mTimer.start();
    }
}
private void stop() {
    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that all the UI is stuck for the 5 second play... I cannot volume up or down, scroll, etc...

Comment: If the UI is stuck, you actually may need a thread. What's that playSound() method do?